# Django DRF - Restrict Access to List View via Permissions

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, permissions, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF ViewSet to which I am adding the `CanViewAndEditStaff` permission. I want only certain users (`user.access_level < 2`) to be able to view the list of staff. In my Permissions class, how can I differentiate between a call to the `list` view and to the `get` item view. Here is my permissions class:

```
class CanViewAndEditStaff(permissions.BasePermission):

        def has_permission(self, request, view):

            # IF THIS IS A LIST VIEW, CHECK ACCESS LEVEL
            if ( request.user.access_level < 3 ):
                return True

            # ELSE, CONTINUE ON TO OBJECT PERMISSIONS

        def has_object_permission(self,request,view,account):

            # admin can do anything
            if ( request.user.access_level == 1 ):
                return True

            # view/edit/delete
            else:

                # users can view their own account
                if  account == request.user:
                    return True

                elif account.access_level >= request.user.access_level:
                    return True

            return False
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class CanViewAndEditStaff(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        # IF THIS IS A LIST VIEW, CHECK ACCESS LEVEL
        if (view.action == 'list' and request.user.access_level < 3 ):
            return True

        # ELSE, CONTINUE ON TO OBJECT PERMISSIONS
```

you can use view.action to know if this is list or something else.

Comment: If he's using `GenericViewSet` or its subclasses for `view` then `self.action` could be used to distinguish between view methods. else, he must use `request.method` t distinguish between request methods

Comment: For those curios, the available actions are `create`, `retrieve`, `update`, '`partial_update`, `destroy`, and `list`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't *exactly* address the question, but this technique is applicable.

I used a variation on Ykh's answer that allows the same permission class to be used broadly across many views which display a variety of different models.

In my view class I added an attribute to distinguish the originating view, thus allowing the appropriate object comparison to determine permissions

```
# views.py
class SomeView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsPermd, )
    is_some_view = True

class SomeOtherView(RetrieveAPIView
    permission_classes = (IsPermd, )
    is_some_other_view = True

# permissions.py
class IsPermd(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permissions(self, request, view, obj):
        if hasattr(view, 'is_some_view'):
            # whatever special considerations
        if hasattr(view, 'is_some_other_view'):
            # whatever other special considerations
```

This feels a little clunky, but until I find a better way I'll stick with it.